# GCM push notification error: MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use GCM to push messages to my android phone.

Whatever I try, I always have the same error: `MismatchSenderId`

I'm testing with a simple curl from CLI.

I generated 3 keys and i tried all 3:

- one for server  `AIzaSyDXz6HLhnRsyyBSKVpdsSrPEC8rFfFbHY8`
- one for browser  `AIzaSyDAyBIP1Qlitli5Yj-F9VIORPwLLCCn3Vo`
- one for android  `AIzaSyCAum68Fu6U7LXpRkq0lLnCti9xQfBgL3s`

My Project ID is `starlit-verve-773` and my Project Number is `401070672185`.

My registration ID is

```
APA91bENhVHjlNaf1OPo0VrxblBKkePzIcm14C4S7E0BSXsKDm9Nk0yk15Mwv54GFgPh5pP_gJTjp5Q3a5Xdfn4N8210GScD2fLmg73xDJBuaRVvjGOTh8juws5dbhYDpiSzGlaP1IhLaX6Vf9-rEEEn-JWrSa9oXUe9T7fMzgTLLrPHEosRUNw
```

I tried 2 curl commands:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<key>" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"<reg ID>\"]}"
curl --header "Authorization: key=<key>" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"<reg ID>\"],\"data\":{\"message\":\"Hello\"}}"
```

My php server has the same error when it tried to push a message.

I got my reg ID with 2 methods:
- an app which send the reg ID to a web server with php and mysql
- logs from eclipse when i launch this app

I'm stuck on this for 2 days now.
I tried to open a new developer project with not the same google account which is on my phone.
I don't know if this is normal but the reg ID is still the same with 2 different project.

For what I understand, my phone should have a different reg ID for each project.

Is the reg ID the problem and how can I fix this?
Is there another way to get the reg ID?

i know there is a lot of questions with this problem but none has worker for me.

Comment: Does mentioning those keys not expose any sensitive information? And you say a lot of answers to various questions did not work for you, could you elaborate on those solutions?

Comment: yes but keys can be regenerated and project deleted. i tried to switch the server key and browser key, same result. i tried to switch the project ID and project number as sender ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "[YOUR API KEY]");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message) 
{
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "[Attr]" => '[val]', "[Attr]" => '[val]'),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

$reg_id = "******";
$msg = 'hi!';

send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $msg);
```